# Flask - Correctjinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting error Flask - `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html`

On the line: `{% extends "base.html"%} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}`

But if I'll render the base.html template there's no issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. In this case it needs to be:
`{% extends "theme/blog/base.html"%} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}`